# Banshee isn't starting anymore

Tags: banshee

my banshee doesn't start anymore. i tried to start it over the terminal just to see if something is broken but all the terminal gave me was this:

```
moere@SAMSUNG-NF110:~$ banshee
[Info  18:45:29.413] Running Banshee 2.2.0: [Ubuntu oneiric (development branch) (linux-gnu, i686) @ 2011-09-23 04:51:00 UTC]
Exception in Gtk# callback delegate
  Note: Applications can use GLib.ExceptionManager.UnhandledException to handle the exception.
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
  at Hyena.Gui.Canvas.Rect.set_Height (Double value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Gui.Canvas.Rect.op_Explicit (Rectangle rect) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Data.Gui.ListView`1[Banshee.Collection.AlbumInfo].OnSizeAllocated (Rectangle allocation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb (IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at GLib.ExceptionManager.RaiseUnhandledException(System.Exception e, Boolean is_terminal)
   at Gtk.Widget.sizeallocated_cb(IntPtr widget, IntPtr allocation)
   at Gtk.Widget.gtksharp_widget_base_show(IntPtr )
   at Gtk.Widget.OnShown()
   at Nereid.PlayerInterface.OnShown()
   at Gtk.Widget.shown_cb(IntPtr widget)
   at Gtk.Widget.gtk_widget_show(IntPtr )
   at Gtk.Widget.Show()
   at Banshee.Gui.BaseClientWindow.InitialShowPresent()
   at Nereid.PlayerInterface.Initialize()
   at Banshee.Gui.BaseClientWindow.InitializeWindow()
   at Banshee.Gui.BaseClientWindow..ctor(System.String title, System.String configNameSpace, Int32 defaultWidth, Int32 defaultHeight)
   at Nereid.PlayerInterface..ctor()
   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod , System.Object , System.Object[] , System.Exception ByRef )
   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke(System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(System.Object[] parameters)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type)
   at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.RegisterService(System.Type type)
   at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.Run()
   at Banshee.ServiceStack.Application.Run()
   at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Initialize(Boolean registerCommonServices)
   at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient..ctor(Boolean initializeDefault, System.String defaultIconName)
   at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient..ctor()
   at Nereid.Client..ctor()
   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoCMethod , System.Object , System.Object[] , System.Exception ByRef )
   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke(System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(System.Object[] parameters)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type)
   at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup()
   at Hyena.Gui.CleanRoomStartup.Startup(Hyena.Gui.StartupInvocationHandler startup)
   at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup()
   at Banshee.Gui.GtkBaseClient.Startup(System.String[] args)
   at Nereid.Client.Main(System.String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(System.AppDomain , System.Reflection.Assembly , System.String[] )
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssemblyInternal(System.Reflection.Assembly a, System.String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(System.String assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(System.String assemblyFile)
   at Booter.Booter.BootClient(System.String clientName)
   at Booter.Booter.Main()
moere@SAMSUNG-NF110:~$
```

so i have no clue what to do. i already tried:

```
sudo apt-get purge banshee; sudo apt-get install banshee
```

and after that removing

```
~/.gconf/apps/banshee-1
~/.cache/banshee-1
~/.config/banshee-1
```

but nothing helped me out. 
muinshee is working fine ...
any suggestions?

update: i tried using sudo banshee and it worked

```
`moere@SAMSUNG-NF110:~$ sudo banshee
[sudo] password for moere: 
[Info  19:23:21.402] Running Banshee 2.2.0: [Ubuntu oneiric (development branch)     (linux-gnu, i686) @ 2011-09-23 04:51:00 UTC]
[Warn  19:23:22.717] DBus support could not be started. Disabling for this session. -     System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
    Parameter name: address (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Bus.Open (System.String address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
System.Exception: Unable to open the session message bus. (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.BusG.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.DBusConnection.Connect (System.String serviceName, Boolean init) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.DBusConnection.Connect (System.String serviceName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Info  19:23:25.303] Updating web proxy from GConf
[Warn  19:23:25.664] Caught an exception - System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: address (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Bus.Open (System.String address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  19:23:25.665] Extension `Banshee.SoundMenu.SoundMenuService' not started: Unable to open the session message bus.
[Warn  19:23:25.671] Caught an exception - System.ApplicationException: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached. (in `Banshee.MultimediaKeys')
  at Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService.Banshee.ServiceStack.IExtensionService.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.StartExtension (Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode node) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  19:23:25.672] Extension `Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService' not started: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached.

(Banshee:4324): Gtk-WARNING **: Refusing to add non-unique action 'CloseAction' to action group 'Global'
[Warn  19:23:25.820] Caught an exception - System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: address (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Bus.Open (System.String address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  19:23:25.820] Extension `Banshee.SoundMenu.SoundMenuService' not started: Unable to open the session message bus.
[Warn  19:23:25.821] Caught an exception - System.ApplicationException: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached. (in `Banshee.MultimediaKeys')
  at Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService.Banshee.ServiceStack.IExtensionService.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.StartExtension (Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode node) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  19:23:25.821] Extension `Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService' not started: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached.
[Info  19:23:25.827] All services are started 3,102282
[Info  19:23:27.355] AmazonMP3 store redirect URL: https://one.ubuntu.com/music/store/amz/
[Info  19:23:28.948] nereid Client Started
[Info  19:23:29.300] GStreamer version 0.10.35.0, gapless: True, replaygain: False`
```

but afterwards i tried it the "normal" way again and it resulted the same as in my first try using banshee in terminal. so it it's still broken.

Comment: Wow. I thought I was the only one to experience this problem. For me clearing `~/.cache/banshee-1` worked.

Comment: yes, i found some solutions 5 min. ago telling me to do this. But as you can see i already tried this and it changed nothing :(

Comment: I reported a bug on launchpad and on their bug tracker, and got no reply on either :/

Comment: ok maybe this helps: running banshee in terminal using sudo worked ... after that i tried only banshee again and nothing happend again...

Comment: have you by any chance installed the ATI proprietary driver version 11.9?  Cause I downloaded and installed that and banshee crash on start.  In fact I don't think 11.9 is working at all, so i switched back to 11.8 and things worked fine.

Comment: no i have an intel card

Comment: And I have a nVidia :D

Comment: ok. i'm not really shure if this is the reason, but at least my banshee is finally working again.
i loged myself off, and loged in again as the guest user. then started banshee and it worked. then i changed back to my account and tried starting banshee, because i was wondering that it works as a guest, and surprisingly banshee opend... strange

Answer (score 1):

What Monton0815 did worked for me:

1. Log on as the Guest user
2. Start Banshee
3. Log out
4. Log in to the user account where Banshee isn't working
5. Start Banshee
6. Happy Days

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this worked for me also

1. Log on as the Guest user
2. Start Banshee
3. Log out
4. Log in to the user account where Banshee isn't working
5. Start Banshee