# Banshee has become unresponsive on open

Tags: 14.04, banshee

Running Banshee from my main user suddenly stopped working. If I run Banshee from my main user without `sudo`, a blank grey window opens and is unresponsive. I've tried everything described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86675/banshee-wont-open) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64846/banshee-isnt-starting-anymore), but with no luck.

Here is my terminal output without sudo:

```
mainuser@laptop:~$ banshee
[Info  16:20:19.132] Running Banshee 2.6.2: [Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (linux-gnu, x86_64) @ 2014-08-12 14:04:38 UTC]

(Banshee:14844): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkComponent) to class (__gtksharp_49_Hyena_Gui_BaseWidgetAccessible) after class_init
(Banshee:14844): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_50_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_TrackInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14844): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_50_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_TrackInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14844): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_56_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_Database_QueryFilterInfo+601+5b+5bSystem_String+2c+20mscorlib+2c+20Version+3d4_0_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3db77a5c561934e089+5d+5d+2c+20Banshee_Services+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init    
(Banshee:14844): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_56_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_Database_QueryFilterInfo+601+5b+5bSystem_String+2c+20mscorlib+2c+20Version+3d4_0_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3db77a5c561934e089+5d+5d+2c+20Banshee_Services+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14844): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_62_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_ArtistInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14844): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_62_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_ArtistInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14844): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_68_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_YearInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14844): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_68_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_YearInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init 
(Banshee:14844): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_74_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_AlbumInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14844): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_74_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_AlbumInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
[Info  16:20:21.176] Updating web proxy from GConf
[Info  16:20:21.309] All services are started 1.869307
(Banshee:14844): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 144 was not found when attempting to remove it  
(Banshee:14844): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 113 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

And here is the output *with* sudo:

```
mainuser@laptop:~$ sudo banshee
[Warn  16:24:02.691] DBus support could not be started. Disabling for this session. - System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: address (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Bus.Open (System.String address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
System.Exception: Unable to open the session message bus. (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.BusG.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.DBusConnection.Connect (System.String serviceName, Boolean init) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.DBusConnection.GrabDefaultName () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Info  16:24:02.734] Running Banshee 2.6.2: [Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (linux-gnu, x86_64) @ 2014-08-12 14:04:38 UTC]
(Banshee:14943): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkComponent) to class (__gtksharp_49_Hyena_Gui_BaseWidgetAccessible) after class_init
(Banshee:14943): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_50_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_TrackInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14943): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_50_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_TrackInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14943): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_56_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_Database_QueryFilterInfo+601+5b+5bSystem_String+2c+20mscorlib+2c+20Version+3d4_0_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3db77a5c561934e089+5d+5d+2c+20Banshee_Services+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14943): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_56_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_Database_QueryFilterInfo+601+5b+5bSystem_String+2c+20mscorlib+2c+20Version+3d4_0_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3db77a5c561934e089+5d+5d+2c+20Banshee_Services+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14943): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_62_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_ArtistInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14943): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_62_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_ArtistInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14943): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_68_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_YearInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14943): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_68_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_YearInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
(Banshee:14943): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkTable) to class (__gtksharp_74_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_AlbumInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_in
(Banshee:14943): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (AtkSelection) to class (__gtksharp_74_Hyena_Data_Gui_Accessibility_ListViewAccessible+601+5b+5bBanshee_Collection_AlbumInfo+2c+20Banshee_Core+2c+20Version+3d2_6_0_0+2c+20Culture+3dneutral+2c+20PublicKeyToken+3dnull+5d+5d) after class_init
[Info  16:24:04.522] Updating web proxy from GConf
[Warn  16:24:04.638] Caught an exception - System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: address (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Bus.Open (System.String address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  16:24:04.638] Extension `Banshee.SoundMenu.SoundMenuService' not started: Unable to open the session message bus.
[Warn  16:24:04.641] Caught an exception - System.ApplicationException: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached. (in `Banshee.MultimediaKeys')
  at Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService.Banshee.ServiceStack.IExtensionService.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.StartExtension (Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode node) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  16:24:04.641] Extension `Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService' not started: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached.
(Banshee:14943): Gtk-WARNING **: Refusing to add non-unique action 'CloseAction' to action group 'Global'
[Warn  16:24:04.719] Caught an exception - System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: address (in `dbus-sharp')
  at DBus.Bus.Open (System.String address) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at DBus.Bus.get_Session () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  16:24:04.719] Extension `Banshee.SoundMenu.SoundMenuService' not started: Unable to open the session message bus.
[Warn  16:24:04.720] Caught an exception - System.ApplicationException: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached. (in `Banshee.MultimediaKeys')
  at Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService.Banshee.ServiceStack.IExtensionService.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.ServiceManager.StartExtension (Mono.Addins.TypeExtensionNode node) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[Warn  16:24:04.720] Extension `Banshee.MultimediaKeys.MultimediaKeysService' not started: No support GNOME Settings Daemon could be reached.
[Info  16:24:04.722] All services are started 1.438745
(Banshee:14943): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 106 was not found when attempting to remove it
(Banshee:14943): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 137 was not found when attempting to remove it
[Info  16:24:05.304] AmazonMP3 store redirect URL: http://integrated-services.banshee.fm/amz/redirect.do/
(Banshee:14943): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 247 was not found when attempting to remove it
(Banshee:14943): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 246 was not found when attempting to remove it
[Info  16:24:05.831] nereid Client Started
[Info  16:24:05.924] GStreamer version 1.2.4.0, gapless: True, replaygain: False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed, either 1) due to multiple reboots and/or 2) because I ran `alsactl nrestore`. This hasn't affected the terminal output in any obvious way, but I Banshee is working normally now, even after restoring my original `~/.config/banshee-1/` folder. I have no idea why this worked, but it will do for now.